# Using php or javascript to log a user into a directory protected with Apache Basic Authentication (htaccess/htpasswd)

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, basic-authentication

Is it possible to use PHP or Javascript to login to a directory protected with Apache Basic Authentication?

A simple example:

- I have a directory called 'protected' (ie. http://myurl/protected) that uses apache basic authentication
- I have a form located at http://myurl/login.php with a username and password field
- When a user enters their username/password into login.php and hits submit,  either php or javascript automatically logs the user into the protected area and redirects them.
- When the user is redirected, they do not have to re-enter their username/password information, and they have full access to the information in the protected directory.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Update:
Do to my client's implementation requirements, I can not use a php based authentication system. It needs to be apache authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use

```
header("Location: http://$username:$password@myurl.com/protected");
```

Although, I would advise against it, and use a php based authentication mentioned above without the Apache basic authentication.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. Why do you advise against it?

Comment: creates an unnecessary dependency between the webserver and your application, spans the implementation of authentication between application tiers, prohibits you to switch to use ssl to have safer authentication

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about the basic authentication with apache is that it is, by definition, basic.  If you are willing to work with php and mysql, you can build a simple login system that would suit your needs.
Just check a username and password against its counterparts in a mysql database (of course hash the password with md5, or sha256), and if it is correct, set a session variable saying so.  Check that variable on each page that needs authentication, and redirect if it isn't set/set to false.

Here is a good example: http://progtuts.info/92/login-system/